# How does a "research scientist" differ from a "scientist"?

Tags: word-usage, redundancy, professions

I have seen the term *research scientist* in several job descriptions. Does the qualifier *research* distinguish a special kind of scientific role, or is this actually a redundant phrase? How can you work as a scientist without doing research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overlap of areas of work between science and research science.

The definition of *science* according to [FreeDictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/science)

> The observation, identification, description, experimental investigation, and theoretical explanation of phenomena

This implies that a scientist proposes a theory and ratifies it by observation and verification. This is **basic science** / **theoretical science**. It has very open scope, therefore much flexibility.

Whereas **research science** / **applied science** is both research and its application in practice. So, there are jobs of Research Scientists at Bell Laboratories, IBM R&D, Google Labs etc. It involves doing work on a specified requirement (probably with customers) and develop a product solution. So, it has narrower scope than basic science.

Comment: >  is apparently both research and its application in practice

Comment: Sorry, I have some struggles with the web interface. I meant to ask if the word "research" is synonymous with "science" in that sentence?

Comment: Good answer! Could you please edit to use conventional formatting though instead of `code` quoting? Long quotes should use > block quotes and emphasis should use *italics* or **bold** type.

Comment: @Jensen No, research and science aren't synonymous, but they are related. Engineers and academics and doctors can be researchers too.

Comment: @BraddSzonye thanks for suggestion about formatting.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for explaining and making the answer nice and readable!

Answer (score 2):

In this sense, "research" is a specific term referring to controlled experiments or trials, generally conducted in a laboratory.

For example, a chemical company might employ research scientists to come up with new polymers. But it will also employ other scientists to develop that research into commercial applications (applied science).

In the world of academia, there are also pure theoreticians, such as Albert Einstein or Stephen Hawking, who generate new ideas for others to test in the laboratory.

Answer (score 1):

"Scientist" covers all people who practice science, particularly those who practice science professionally. "Research scientist" refers to someone who is using scientific methods to learn something new about the way the world works even if it's in a very specific area. For instance people developing drugs are research scientists because they are looking for a new way to cure or alleviate illnesses.

Examples of scientists who are not research scientists are forensic scientists and medical scientists. These people use established scientific techniques to find out which of a number of established circumstances or conditions apply in the particular case they are studying, they are not, usually, trying to discover something new.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one which does not make the distinction between a research scientist and non-research scientists clearly. A high level of a particular type of scientific knowledge and skill is required in research (to discover something new) but that same level may be needed in analysis (forensic, medical, metallurgical etc) or in the development of processes in chemical or bio-engineering companies. The majority of graduating scientists who stay pursue a scientific career do not do research.